# Drupal with postgres in docker throws error 'relation "cache_discovery" does not exist'

Tags: postgresql, docker, drupal

I'm running `drupal` with `postgres` in `docker` on `GCP ubuntu 18.04` instance. When I'm trying to install the `drupal` via `browser` resulting in below error in `postgres` container logs.

> drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 08:57:48.693 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
>
> drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 09:00:03.642 UTC [61] ERROR:  relation "cache_discovery" does not exist at character 13
>
> drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 09:00:03.642 UTC [61] STATEMENT:  DELETE FROM cache_discovery
>
> drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |     WHERE cid IN ('typed_config_definitions')
>
> drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 09:00:03.684 UTC [61] ERROR:  relation "cache_bootstrap" does not exist at character 68
>
> drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 09:00:03.684 UTC [61] STATEMENT:  SELECT cid, data, created, expire, serialized, tags, checksum FROM cache_bootstrap WHERE cid IN ( 'module_implements' ) ORDER BY cid

I have tried different `drupal` and `postgres` versions but getting same error.

**Versions tried**

`Drupal:latest,8.8,8.7,8.2,7`

`Postgres:latest,11,10,9`

**docker file**

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  drupal:
    image: drupal:8.8
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - drupal-modules:/var/www/html/modules
      - drupal-profiles:/var/www/html/profiles
      - drupal-sites:/var/www/html/sites
      - drupal-themes:/var/www/html/themes

  postgres:
    image: postgres:10
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/psql_pass
    secrets:
      - psql_pass
    volumes:
      - drupal-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  drupal-data:
  drupal-modules:
  drupal-profiles:
  drupal-sites:
  drupal-themes:

secrets:
  psql_pass:
    external: true
```

**Complete logs**

postgres container logs

```
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | This user must also own the server process.
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | Data page checksums are disabled.
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | creating subdirectories ... ok
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | selecting default max_connections ... 100
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | selecting default timezone ... Etc/UTC
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | creating configuration files ... ok
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | running bootstrap script ... ok
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | syncing data to disk ... ok
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | Success. You can now start the database server using:
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | waiting for server to start....2020-01-26 08:57:48.460 UTC [44] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 08:57:48.485 UTC [45] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-01-26 08:57:47 UTC
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 08:57:48.491 UTC [44] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |  done
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | server started
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 08:57:48.549 UTC [44] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | waiting for server to shut down....2020-01-26 08:57:48.552 UTC [44] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 08:57:48.554 UTC [44] LOG:  worker process: logical replication launcher (PID 51) exited with exit code 1
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 08:57:48.558 UTC [46] LOG:  shutting down
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 08:57:48.574 UTC [44] LOG:  database system is shut down
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |  done
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | server stopped
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 08:57:48.666 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 08:57:48.666 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 08:57:48.671 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 08:57:48.688 UTC [53] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-01-26 08:57:48 UTC
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 08:57:48.693 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 09:00:03.642 UTC [61] ERROR:  relation "cache_discovery" does not exist at character 13
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 09:00:03.642 UTC [61] STATEMENT:  DELETE FROM cache_discovery
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |     WHERE cid IN ('typed_config_definitions')
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 09:00:03.684 UTC [61] ERROR:  relation "cache_bootstrap" does not exist at character 68
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 09:00:03.684 UTC [61] STATEMENT:  SELECT cid, data, created, expire, serialized, tags, checksum FROM cache_bootstrap WHERE cid IN ( 'module_implements' ) ORDER BY cid
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 09:00:03.685 UTC [61] ERROR:  relation "cache_bootstrap" does not exist at character 68
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 09:00:03.685 UTC [61] STATEMENT:  SELECT cid, data, created, expire, serialized, tags, checksum FROM cache_bootstrap WHERE cid IN ( 'hook_info' ) ORDER BY cid    drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 09:00:03.688 UTC [61] ERROR:  relation "public.cache_bootstrap" does not exist at character 409
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 09:00:03.688 UTC [61] STATEMENT:  SELECT pg_attribute.attname AS column_name, format_type(pg_attribute.atttypid, pg_attribute.atttypmod) AS data_type, pg_get_expr(pg_attrdef.adbin, pg_attribute.attrelid) AS column_default
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |     FROM pg_attribute
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |     LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef ON pg_attrdef.adrelid = pg_attribute.attrelid AND pg_attrdef.adnum = pg_attribute.attnum
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |     WHERE pg_attribute.attnum > 0
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |     AND NOT pg_attribute.attisdropped
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |     AND pg_attribute.attrelid = 'public.cache_bootstrap'::regclass
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |     AND (format_type(pg_attribute.atttypid, pg_attribute.atttypmod) = 'bytea'
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |     OR pg_attrdef.adsrc::text LIKE 'nextval%')
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 09:00:03.717 UTC [61] ERROR:  relation "cachetags" does not exist at character 32
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 09:00:03.717 UTC [61] STATEMENT:  SELECT tag, invalidations FROM cachetags WHERE tag IN ( 'entity_types' )
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 09:00:03.736 UTC [61] ERROR:  relation "config" does not exist at character 29
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 09:00:03.736 UTC [61] STATEMENT:  SELECT 1 AS expression
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |     FROM
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |     config config
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |     WHERE (collection = '') AND (name = 'core.extension')
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 09:00:03.754 UTC [61] ERROR:  relation "public.cache_config" does not exist at character 409
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 09:00:03.754 UTC [61] STATEMENT:  SELECT pg_attribute.attname AS column_name, format_type(pg_attribute.atttypid, pg_attribute.atttypmod) AS data_type, pg_get_expr(pg_attrdef.adbin, pg_attribute.attrelid) AS column_default
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |     FROM pg_attribute
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |     LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef ON pg_attrdef.adrelid = pg_attribute.attrelid AND pg_attrdef.adnum = pg_attribute.attnum
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |     WHERE pg_attribute.attnum > 0
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |     AND NOT pg_attribute.attisdropped
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |     AND pg_attribute.attrelid = 'public.cache_config'::regclass
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |     AND (format_type(pg_attribute.atttypid, pg_attribute.atttypmod) = 'bytea'
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |     OR pg_attrdef.adsrc::text LIKE 'nextval%')
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 09:00:03.822 UTC [61] ERROR:  relation "cache_default" does not exist at character 13
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 09:00:03.822 UTC [61] STATEMENT:  DELETE FROM cache_default
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |     WHERE cid IN ('core.extension.list.module')
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 09:00:03.849 UTC [61] ERROR:  relation "key_value" does not exist at character 13
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 09:00:03.849 UTC [61] STATEMENT:  DELETE FROM key_value
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |     WHERE (name IN ('system.module.files')) AND (collection = 'state')
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 09:00:03.903 UTC [61] ERROR:  relation "key_value" does not exist at character 13
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 09:00:03.903 UTC [61] STATEMENT:  DELETE FROM key_value
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |     WHERE (name IN ('system.module.files')) AND (collection = 'state')
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 09:00:04.215 UTC [61] ERROR:  relation "public.cache_menu" does not exist at character 409
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    | 2020-01-26 09:00:04.215 UTC [61] STATEMENT:  SELECT pg_attribute.attname AS column_name, format_type(pg_attribute.atttypid, pg_attribute.atttypmod) AS data_type, pg_get_expr(pg_attrdef.adbin, pg_attribute.attrelid) AS column_default
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |     FROM pg_attribute
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |     LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef ON pg_attrdef.adrelid = pg_attribute.attrelid AND pg_attrdef.adnum = pg_attribute.attnum
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |     WHERE pg_attribute.attnum > 0
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |     AND NOT pg_attribute.attisdropped
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |     AND pg_attribute.attrelid = 'public.cache_menu'::regclass
drupal_postgres.1.lsuys33bg8jt@gcloud1    |     AND (format_type(pg_attribute.atttypid, pg_attribute.atttypmod) = 'bytea'
```

drupal container logs

```
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.0.11.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.0.11.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message     drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | [Sun Jan 26 08:58:03.157424 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) PHP/7.3.14 configured -- resuming normal operations
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | [Sun Jan 26 08:58:03.157748 2020] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:08:59:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 609 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:08:59:27 +0000] "GET /core/install.php HTTP/1.1" 200 4288 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:08:59:28 +0000] "GET /core/misc/normalize-fixes.css?0 HTTP/1.1" 200 534 "http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/install.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:08:59:28 +0000] "GET /core/themes/seven/css/components/container-inline.css?0 HTTP/1.1" 200 513 "http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/install.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:08:59:28 +0000] "GET /core/themes/seven/css/components/details.css?0 HTTP/1.1" 200 604 "http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/install.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:08:59:28 +0000] "GET /core/themes/seven/css/components/container-inline.module.css?0 HTTP/1.1" 200 435 "http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/install.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:08:59:28 +0000] "GET /core/themes/seven/css/components/system-status-counter.css?0 HTTP/1.1" 200 1024 "http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/install.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:08:59:28 +0000] "GET /core/themes/seven/css/components/system-status-report-general-info.css?0 HTTP/1.1" 200 1244 "http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/install.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:08:59:28 +0000] "GET /core/themes/seven/css/components/system-status-report-counters.css?0 HTTP/1.1" 200 588 "http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/install.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:08:59:28 +0000] "GET /core/themes/seven/css/theme/colors.css?0 HTTP/1.1" 200 478 "http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/install.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:08:59:28 +0000] "GET /core/assets/vendor/jquery-once/jquery.once.min.js?v=2.2.0 HTTP/1.1" 200 777 "http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/install.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:08:59:28 +0000] "GET /core/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=3.4.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 31030 "http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/install.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:08:59:28 +0000] "GET /core/misc/drupalSettingsLoader.js?v=8.8.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 663 "http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/install.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:08:59:28 +0000] "GET /core/misc/drupal.init.js?v=8.8.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 738 "http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/install.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:08:59:28 +0000] "GET /core/misc/drupal.js?v=8.8.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 2206 "http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/install.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:08:59:28 +0000] "GET /core/misc/states.js?v=8.8.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 3044 "http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/install.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:08:59:28 +0000] "GET /core/themes/seven/js/mobile.install.js?v=8.8.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 832 "http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/install.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:08:59:30 +0000] "POST /core/install.php HTTP/1.1" 302 828 "http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/install.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:08:59:31 +0000] "GET /core/install.php?rewrite=ok&langcode=en HTTP/1.1" 200 3131 "http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/install.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:08:59:31 +0000] "GET /core/misc/icons/e29700/warning.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 700 "http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/themes/classy/css/components/messages.css?0" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:08:59:33 +0000] "POST /core/install.php?rewrite=ok&langcode=en HTTP/1.1" 302 929 "http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/install.php?rewrite=ok&langcode=en" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:08:59:33 +0000] "GET /core/install.php?rewrite=ok&langcode=en&profile=standard HTTP/1.1" 200 4074 "http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/install.php?rewrite=ok&langcode=en" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:08:59:33 +0000] "GET /core/misc/details-aria.js?v=8.8.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 714 "http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/install.php?rewrite=ok&langcode=en&profile=standard" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:08:59:33 +0000] "GET /core/misc/debounce.js?v=8.8.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 751 "http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/install.php?rewrite=ok&langcode=en&profile=standard" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:08:59:33 +0000] "GET /core/misc/collapse.js?v=8.8.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 1429 "http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/install.php?rewrite=ok&langcode=en&profile=standard" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:08:59:33 +0000] "GET /core/misc/form.js?v=8.8.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 1858 "http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/install.php?rewrite=ok&langcode=en&profile=standard" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jan/2020:08:59:41 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) PHP/7.3.14 (internal dummy connection)"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jan/2020:08:59:42 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) PHP/7.3.14 (internal dummy connection)"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:09:00:03 +0000] "POST /core/install.php?rewrite=ok&langcode=en&profile=standard HTTP/1.1" 302 1199 "http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/install.php?rewrite=ok&langcode=en&profile=standard" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | [Sun Jan 26 09:00:06.452298 2020] [php7:notice] [pid 17] [client 10.0.0.2:63426] RuntimeException: Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by "/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php" at line 361. in /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php on line 145 #0 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Session/SessionManager.php(164): Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Session\\Storage\\NativeSessionStorage->start()\n#1 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Session/SessionManager.php(195): Drupal\\Core\\Session\\SessionManager->startNow()\n#2 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Session.php(196): Drupal\\Core\\Session\\SessionManager->save()\n#3 /var/www/html/core/includes/install.core.inc(149): Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Session\\Session->save()\n#4 /var/www/html/core/install.php(44): install_drupal(Object(Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader))\n#5 {main}, referer: http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/install.php?rewrite=ok&langcode=en&profile=standard
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:09:00:06 +0000] "GET /core/install.php?rewrite=ok&langcode=en&profile=standard&id=1&op=start HTTP/1.1" 302 12008 "http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/install.php?rewrite=ok&langcode=en&profile=standard" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:09:00:06 +0000] "GET /core/install.php/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4372 "http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/install.php?rewrite=ok&langcode=en&profile=standard" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:09:00:11 +0000] "POST /core/install.php/ HTTP/1.1" 302 828 "http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/install.php/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:09:00:12 +0000] "GET /core/install.php?rewrite=ok&langcode=en HTTP/1.1" 200 3212 "http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/install.php/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:09:00:14 +0000] "POST /core/install.php?rewrite=ok&langcode=en HTTP/1.1" 302 929 "http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/install.php?rewrite=ok&langcode=en" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | [Sun Jan 26 09:00:14.735354 2020] [php7:notice] [pid 22] [client 10.0.0.2:63432] Drupal\\Core\\Config\\UnmetDependenciesException: Configuration objects provided by <em class="placeholder">standard</em> have unmet dependencies: <em class="placeholder">block.block.bartik_account_menu (block), block.block.bartik_help (help, block), block.block.bartik_search (search, block), block_content.type.basic (block_content), comment.type.comment (comment), contact.form.feedback (contact), core.entity_form_display.block_content.basic.default (text), core.entity_form_display.node.article.default (image.style.thumbnail, comment, image, path, text), core.entity_form_display.node.page.default (path, text), core.entity_form_display.user.user.default (image.style.thumbnail, image), core.entity_view_display.node.article.default (image.style.large, comment, image, text), core.entity_view_display.node.article.rss (core.entity_view_mode.node.rss), core.entity_view_display.node.article.teaser (core.entity_view_mode.node.teaser, image.style.medium, image, text), core.entity_view_display.node.page.teaser (core.entity_view_mode.node.teaser, text), editor.editor.basic_html (ckeditor, editor), field.field.block_content.basic.body (field.storage.block_content.body, text, field), field.field.comment.comment.comment_body (field.storage.comment.comment_body, text, field), field.field.node.article.body (field.storage.node.body, text, field), field.field.node.article.comment (comment, field), field.field.node.article.field_image (image, field), field.field.node.article.field_tags (field), field.storage.node.comment (comment, node, field), field.storage.node.field_image (file, image, node, field), field.storage.node.field_tags (node, taxonomy, field), field.storage.user.user_picture (file, image, field), filter.format.basic_html (editor, filter), filter.format.restricted_html (filter), node.type.article (node), rdf.mapping.comment.comment (comment, rdf), rdf.mapping.node.article (node, rdf), rdf.mapping.taxonomy_term.tags (taxonomy, rdf), taxonomy.vocabulary.tags (taxonomy)</em> in /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/UnmetDependenciesException.php on line 98 #0 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/ConfigInstaller.php(509): Drupal\\Core\\Config\\UnmetDependenciesException::create('standard', Array)\n#1 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/ProxyClass/Config/ConfigInstaller.php(132): Drupal\\Core\\Config\\ConfigInstaller->checkConfigurationToInstall('module', 'standard')\n#2 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ModuleInstaller.php(161): Drupal\\Core\\ProxyClass\\Config\\ConfigInstaller->checkConfigurationToInstall('module', 'standard')\n#3 /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/ProxyClass/Extension/ModuleInstaller.php(83): Drupal\\Core\\Extension\\ModuleInstaller->install(Array, false)\n#4 /var/www/html/core/includes/install.core.inc(1644): Drupal\\Core\\ProxyClass\\Extension\\ModuleInstaller->install(Array, false)\n#5 /var/www/html/core/includes/install.core.inc(702): install_install_profile(Array)\n#6 /var/www/html/core/includes/install.core.inc(577): install_run_task(Array, Array)\n#7 /var/www/html/core/includes/install.core.inc(117): install_run_tasks(Array, NULL)\n#8 /var/www/html/core/install.php(44): install_drupal(Object(Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader))\n#9 {main}, referer: http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/install.php?rewrite=ok&langcode=en
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.2 - - [26/Jan/2020:09:00:14 +0000] "GET /core/install.php?rewrite=ok&langcode=en&profile=standard HTTP/1.1" 200 2736 "http://34.93.167.251:8080/core/install.php?rewrite=ok&langcode=en" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.5 - - [26/Jan/2020:09:04:42 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2636 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
drupal_drupal.1.3mr6olwwoyeg@gcloud2    | 10.0.0.5 - - [26/Jan/2020:09:19:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2636 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
```

Please help.